# Can someone get this custom AlertDialog to actually work?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I asked another question about custom AlertDialog [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825720/extending-alertdialogs-in-android-where-to-find-examples-how-to-get-title-and).

Then I clicked my way to this custom AlertDialog (found [here](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/apps-for-android/Translate/src/com/beust/android/translate/AboutDialog.java.shtml)):

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.webkit.WebView;

/**
 * Display a simple about dialog.
 */
public class AboutDialog extends AlertDialog {

    protected AboutDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setContentView(R.layout.about_dialog);

        setTitle(R.string.about_title);
        setCancelable(true);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.loadData("Written by Cédric Beust (<a href=\"mailto:cedric@beust.com\">cedric@beust.com)", "text/html", "utf-8");
    }

}
```

I modified like this:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.webkit.WebView;

/**
 * Display a simple about dialog.
 */
public class AboutDialog extends AlertDialog {

    protected AboutDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setTitle("Test");
        setCancelable(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.paus);
    }
}
```

and then tried to use it, like this:

```
AboutDialog ad = new AboutDialog(getApplicationContext());
ad.show();
```

But I get this error:

```
android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:181)
    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:206)
    at android.app.AlertDialog.onCreate(AlertDialog.java:251)
    at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:307)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:225)
    at TestPackage.MainActivity$5.onClick(MainActivity.java:382)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
  etc...
```

So I'd like to know why this is happening.

===================== EDIT ==========================0

As per suggestions below, I modified the code so it looks like this:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

/**
 * Display a simple about dialog.
 */
public class AboutDialog extends AlertDialog {

    protected AboutDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.paus);

    }
}
```

But I get a **BadTokenException** instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override on create method of altertdialog and call following methods in overridden method oncreate

```
 setContentView(R.layout.paus);
```

this will solve your problem.

Comment: Secondly, that didnt work unfortunately. BadTokenException =( See my update above.

Comment: When you create instance of AboutDialog create it as follows.
AboutDialog ald = new AboutDialog(Activity.this)
Dont use getApplicationContext();

Answer (score 0):

setContentView() must be called before setTitle() ...

Comment: I tried the other way around too... same problem. Thats why I moved setTitle to above setContentView, cause Android complained...

Comment: Forget my answer. I didn't see that you were calling these methods in the constructor. Use the suggesttion of Android_Crazy ...

Answer (score 0):

why don't you add a title (a text view) in R.layout.param and also you can add buttons and then everything  will be shown

Comment: My main point was: take an AlertDialog, and then just tweak some EditText behaviour. I did not want to create a completely custom thing, just take the AlertDialog (with its title, buttons etc), and then just add som OnTextChange listeners to its EditTexts (that I have in my layout file). I can do something like that if I use a normal AlertDialog.Builder, but then **all code ends up in my MainActivity** which is pretty horrible.