# Soft KeyBoard not pop up in EditText of AlertDialog

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

After a lot of search I found various solution of this question but that solution not works for me .I use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455235/when-using-alertdialog-builder-with-edittext-the-soft-keyboard-doesnt-pop)  , but not works for me and i also use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834240/can-someone-get-this-custom-alertdialog-to-actually-work) it also not works for me. Please help me . I am compltely stuck here.

I use following code : from an activity I called a dialog like that :

```
FirstStartDialog dialog=new FirstStartDialog(this);

        dialog.show();
```

then my Dialog class like that :

```
public class FirstStartDialog extends AlertDialog{
public FirstStartDialog(final MainWindow mainWindow,
        ) {
    super(mainWindow);
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.new_account_dialog);
    //getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
     editText_registration_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxt_User_Name);
    editText_registration_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxt_Password);
    _btn_registration_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_registration_next);
    _tap_here_registration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_Tap_Here_Message);
    _relative_Main_new_Account = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_Main_New_Account);



    editText_login_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxt_Existing_User_Name);
    editText_login_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etxt_Exiting_User_Password);
    _btn_login_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login_next);
    _tap_here_login = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_Tap_Here_Existing);
    _relative_Main_Existing_Account = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_Main_Existing_Account);


    editText_registration_username.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                  FirstStartDialog.this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    editText_registration_password.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                FirstStartDialog.this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
    }
  }
```

In xml file i define my EditText like that :

```
  <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/etxt_Password"
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etxt_User_Name"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/login_new_account_editbox"
            />
```

Please help me.

Comment: in your layout, have you set edittext to focusable:true?

Comment: no. i not set this property but when dialog opens its always focus on edit text that is cursor blinks in EditText.

Comment: set inputType to edittext

Comment: @newBee i set  android:inputType="text" but not works .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this way:

> ```
>  public class FirstStartDialog extends Dialog {
> Context context;
>  final AlertDialog.Builder alert;
> public FirstStartDialog(Context p_context) {
>     super(p_context);
>     context = p_context;
>      alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
> }    
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>      LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
>      View container = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_account_dialog, null);
>      final EditText editText_registration_username = (EditText)container.findViewById(R.id.etxt_User_Name);
>         editText_registration_username
>         .setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
>                  if (hasFocus) {                     ((InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
>                  .showSoftInput(editText_registration_username,
>                  InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
>                  }
>             }
>         });
>         setContentView(container);
> }    }
> ```

Implement your dialog as above you will get the keyboard open.

Comment: getSysytemService not works in AlertDialog class . i use this method on Activity Reference but it not works.               ((InputMethodManager)mainWindow.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
.showSoftInput(editText_registration_password, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);

Comment: Checkout i have edited my code and try to implement using this code.

Comment: it works for me but i not use onFoucsChangeListener().. Thanks.