# How i can create Alert dialog with custom title without using xml

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

i want to create Alert Dialog with custom title but without any XML
in fact i want to create class that extends Alert Dialog

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825720/extending-alertdialogs-in-android-where-to-find-examples-how-to-get-title-and), you can apparently extend the `AlertDialog.Builder` class...

Comment: AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("TITLE");
        alert.setMessage("Error");
        alert.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        alert.show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call `setCustomTitle()` on a progmatically confirmed TextView.
**For example:**

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Title Here");

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setCustomTitle(tv);
```